# My logo keeps getting cut off when I resize the screen

Tags: html, css

I have have been trying to figure out this problem for ages. My logo is positioned to the left of my browser and every time i try and resize the browser the beginning gets cut off. It won't let me scroll to the left at all. This is also happening with a footer image I have that is also positioned to the left.

As you can see, you can't see the image but even the description of the image is cut off.
https://jsfiddle.net/2bfdyxat/

And here is the full screen version that looks fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/2bfdyxat/embedded/result/

Thanks for the help!

```
     <div id="header">
     <p id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer" >
     </p>
    </div>

    html,
    body {
    background-image: url(images/background.png);
    width: 98Hi, 9px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    }
    #header {
    margin-top: 40px;
   }

   #logo img {
   width: 320px;
   margin-top: -60px;
   margin-left: -50px;
   }
```

Comment: Why you give margin-left ? just remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove negative margin-left. It is your problem.

```
 margin-left: 0;
```

See this:

https://jsfiddle.net/2bfdyxat/1/

Comment: That was frustratingly simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe, removing margin left causes a problem with your actual layout. I recommend you to analyze slow what is your perfect structure to avoid negative margins in the edge of the document.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please, accept this like correct answer (vote up)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share what works for me:
I had the same problem with the logo image, it was cut off when resizing, and solved by changing the background-size from cover to contain.

```
  background-size: contain;
```